# Contar cuantas palabras acaban en 'a' dada una frase

Tags: javascript

Función que recoja una frase como parámetro y nos devuelva cuántas palabras terminan por a. 
Tengo este código pero me muestra cuantas 'a' hay en la frase, no las palabras que terminan en 'a' y no 
entiendo como solucionarlo.

```js
    function contar() {
        var frase = prompt("Introduce una frase: ");
        var contador = 0;
        for(i=0; i<frase.length; i++){
          if(frase[i] === "a"){
            contador++;
          }else{
          }
        }
        return contador;
      }
      
      alert(contar());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mejor usa [endsWith](https://www.techonthenet.com/js/string_endswith.php), te resolverá mejor el problema. Yo lo haría asi:

Mi funcion hace lo siguiente:

1.- Convierte a minúsculas la cadena que le llega como parametro en la variable "sentence".

2.- Trocea la cadena en un arreglo de palabras llamado allWords.

3.- Filtra y guarda en otro arreglo de palabras las palabras acabadas en la letra "A"

4.- Finalmente devuelve la longitud de este ultimo arreglo que será justo el numero de palabras que acababan en la letra "A".

```
function countEndsWithA(sentence) {
     sentenceLower = sentence.toLowerCase();
     const allWords = sentenceLower.split(/[ ,\.]+/);
     let endsWithA = allWords.filter(word => word.endsWith('a'));
     return endsWithA.length;
}console.log(countEndsWithA("probando la funcion para contar palabras acabadas en la letra A"))
```

Comment: Bueno... aparte de no poner descripción alguna acerca de lo que hiciste, realmente la solución no es mala, no veo porque ponerle voto negativo (excepto por que le hace falta descripción y talvez requiera unas cuantas lineas mas que las otras respuestas), pero de resto me parece bastante adecuada la solución.

Comment: Ahhh ahora entiendo el porque... amigo la idea del OP no era mostrar la cantidad de palabras que terminen en a en una frase, no la longitud, si no las palabras que terminen en a, a lo mejor por eso los votos negativos.

Comment: Yo creo que lo dice bien claro en su comentario inicial el OP, dice "CONTAR" el numero de palabras que acaban en la letra "A" y eso es lo que he hecho...me falta explicárselo, pero enseguida lo edito y lo dejo explicado , a ver si me quitan los negativos.

Comment: Si... es que el titulo no va del todo acorde con el contenido de la pregunta, segun lei en el contenido de la pregunta el dice 'pero me muestra la cantidad de a que hay en la frase, no las palabras que terminan en a', segun entiendo quiso decir que queria era mostrar las palabras que terminasen en a.

Comment: Yo no lo veo así, entiendo que la función se llama CONTAR...es decir, contar en cristiano. Así que a contar se ha dicho. Si la función se llamase showMeTheFuckingWordsEndsWithA si que lo entendería como tu, pero este creo que no es el caso. ¿No crees?

Comment: Cierto...pero es que no me da la vida para mas....bastante hago.

Answer (score 5):

La forma de solucionarlo es en dos pasos:

- encontrar las palabras.
- comprobar si terminan en `a`.

Para lo primero puedes usar el método [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split), que dividirá el string en trozos según el separador que uses (lo normal es usar un espacio, aunque puedes tener en cuenta comas o puntos):

```js
const frase = prompt('Introduce una frase');

// podríamos usar simplemente split(' ') para sólo espacios, pero aquí pongo 
// una expresión regular que incluye comas y puntos
const palabras = frase.split(/[ ,\.]+/);

console.log('Las palabras encontradas son', palabras);
```

Luego sólo tienes que recorrer la lista de palabras para encontrar las que terminan en 'a', lo que podrías hacer con un bucle o usando el método [`filter` de la clase `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter), que filtra los elementos que no cumplen la condición dada:

```js
const palabras = [ 'Esta','frase','tiene','hasta','seis','palabras'];

const terminanEnA = palabras.filter(palabra => palabra.endsWith('a'));

console.log(terminanEnA)
```

Comment: Correcto, lo que pasa es que no quiero hacerle todo el ejercicio, sólo darle las pistas para que OP pueda montar una solución

Answer (score 4):

Lo puedes hacer asi:

- Dentro de la función conviertes a la cadena de texto donde cada una de sus palabras se convierte en un elemento del array nuevo
- Declaras una variable contador que al final nos dirá cuantas palabras terminan en A
- Con un ciclo iteras el recién creado array
- Por cada iteración verificas con una expresión si el elemento termina en a y entonces aumentas en 1 al contador
- Por fuera del ciclo y del condicional retornas al contador

Código:

```js
    function cuentaLetra(palabras) {
      let palabra = palabras.split(" ")
      let contador = 0
      for (individual of palabra) {
        if(/[a]$/.test(individual)) {
          contador += 1
        }
      }
      return contador
    }
    
    console.log(cuentaLetra("hola playa come lluvia"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya tienes 2 muy buenas respuestas, así que aporto mi solución usando un estilo [`one-liner`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program).

Una función que recibe una cadena y te devuelve la cantidad de palabras contenidas en la cadena cuya letra final es `a`:

```js
const frase = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam dolorum excepturi, error eos repellendus laboriosam? Molestiae iusto laboriosam, assumenda, neque totam amet quidem vel officia at eos doloribus error iure.';

// haciéndolo extensible:
const cantPalabrasTerminanEn = (cadena, letra) => {
  return cadena.split(/[ ,\.]+/).filter(palabra => palabra.endsWith(letra)).length;
}

console.log('Terminan en a: ', cantPalabrasTerminanEn(frase, 'a'));

console.log('Terminan en m: ', cantPalabrasTerminanEn(frase, 'm'));
```

Mi aporte para los que gustan de soluciones compactas.

**Edición**

Lo hice extensible, para que pases como argumento la letra con la cual deseas que terminen.